# BinomialDistribution: Plotting probability of obtaining $k \ge k_0$ for fixed $n$ and $p$ between $0$ and $1$

Tags: plotting, distributions

In the setting of the Binomial Distribution, I am trying to figure out how to plot the probability of obtaining $k \ge 31$ for fixed $n$, for success probabilities $p$ between $0$ and $1$.

Why does the code below not work?

```
DiscretePlot[Table[CDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k], {k, {31}}] // Evaluate, {p, 1}, ExtentSize -> Left]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[SurvivalFunction[BinomialDistribution[50, p], 30], {p, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: As noted by @user120911, this function simplifies to  `BetaRegularized[p, 1 + m, -m + n]`

```
FullSimplify[SurvivalFunction[BinomialDistribution[n, p], m],
 {m, n} ∈ Integers && n > m >= 0]
```

> ```
>  BetaRegularized[p, 1 + m, -m + n]
> ```

So

```
Plot[BetaRegularized[p, 1 + 30, -30 + 50], {p, 0, 1}]
```

gives the same picture.

Comment: You need 30,  not 31...

Comment: @kglr, it turns out your solution simplifies nicely to the Regularized Beta Function.

Comment: @user120911, good observation. I added your comment to the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[Probability[k >= 31, 
  k \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[50, p]], 
  {p, 0, 1}]
```

[image]